# How to host BF Skills in Teams App Store?

Tags: botframework, bots

We have a bunch of Microsoft BF Bot Skills that we are using with our Virtual Assistants. Not all skills are applicable to all our users. Teams being our collaboration platform, I was thinking if we could host these skills in our Teams enterprise app store and then let our users dynamically add them to the VA as needed. Is this even possible? Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this would work as they are currently designed. The relationship from bot:skill is managed, primarily, by the bot via AppId's, keys, endpoints, etc., shared between the two. The issue is each skill uploaded into Teams would require it's own manifest whereas normally only one is promoted, the primary bot. By each skill having its own manifest, Teams is going to treat it as an individual app. I believe this would interfere with the bot and skill properly connecting.

That being said, you could forgo the current bot:skill design and create smaller independent bots. By using [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript), it is perfectly feasible to send messages between bots. As a user interacts with the HR bot and answers some question about payroll, that message is forwarded as a proactive message to the Payroll bot which does stuff and then returns a message back to the HR bot and, subsequently, to the user.

Hope of help!